# next element in a associative php array

Tags: php, loops

This seems so easy but i cant figure it out

```
$users_emails = array(
'Spence' => 'spence@someplace.com', 
'Matt'   => 'matt@someplace.com', 
'Marc'   => 'marc@someplace.com', 
'Adam'   => 'adam@someplace.com', 
'Paul'   => 'paul@someplace.com');
```

I need to get the next element in the array but i cant figure it out... so for example

If i have

```
$users_emails['Spence']
```

I need to return matt@someplace.com and if Its

```
$users_emails['Paul']
```

i need start from the top and return spence@someplace.com

i tried this

```
$next_user = (next($users_emails["Spence"]));
```

and this also

```
 ($users_emails["Spence"] + 1 ) % count( $users_emails )
```

but they dont return what i am expecting

Comment: Are associative arrays ordered?

Comment: Is the name you're using in the key a one-time input, or do you need to print all the values out with their corresponding emails?

Comment: Might want to create a circular linked list for this.

Comment: you have to move the array_pointer  to next and prev your self read the Array functions and its there how to iterate array manually

Answer (score 7):

```
reset($array);
while (list($key, $value) = each($array)) { ...
```

Reset() rewind the array pointer to the first element, each() returns the current element key and value as an array then move to the next element.

```
list($key, $value) = each($array);
// is the same thing as
$key = key($array); // get the current key
$value = current($array); // get the current value
next($array); // move the internal pointer to the next element
```

To navigate you can use `next($array)`, `prev($array)`, `reset($array)`, `end($array)`, while the data is read using `current($array)` and/or `key($array)`.

Or you can use foreach if you loop over all of them

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) { ...
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this:

```
$users_emails = array(
'Spence' => 'spence@someplace.com', 
'Matt'   => 'matt@someplace.com', 
'Marc'   => 'marc@someplace.com', 
'Adam'   => 'adam@someplace.com', 
'Paul'   => 'paul@someplace.com');

$current = 'Spence';
$keys = array_keys($users_emails);
$ordinal = (array_search($current,$keys)+1)%count($keys);
$next = $keys[$ordinal];
print_r($users_emails[$next]);
```

However I think you might have an error in your logic and what you are doing can be done better, such as using a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better storing these in an indexed array to achieve the functionality you're looking for